# Get Comments to threads in BigQuery Reddit

Tags: google-bigquery, reddit

I'm trying to get a conversation chain basically for all comments in a subreddit.

For example (total psueudo data structure to illustrate the point) I'm trying to get the following output

```
[I love this game, link_id:0, date]
[I love this game too, parent_id:0, date]
[omg me too, parent_id:0, date]
```

Notice how the second and third relate to the first one by parent_id

I tried doing the following, but I dont think it's getting me the results I want.

```
SELECT *
FROM [fh-bigquery:reddit_comments.2017_03] 
WHERE subreddit IN ('xboxone')
ORDER BY created_utc DESC, link_id DESC
LIMIT 50
```

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/bigquery/comments/4f2yp7/best_way_to_look_at_conversation_chains_in_reddit/

Comment: Comment chains are trees. What kind of structure would represent the output? An array of all the nodes in the tree?